# Get Role Instant Status with Azure Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure

How do I get the Status of a Role Instance in Azure Powershell? I'm using the following command but it's not showing me the Status of the Role

```
Get-AzureRole -ServiceName serviceNameHere
```

This is the output:

```
RoleName             : Role Name
InstanceCount        : 1
DeploymentID         : ***deployment id*******
OSVersion            : ***OSVersion*******
ServiceName          : ***service name*******
OperationDescription : Get-AzureRole  
OperationId          : ***operation id*******
OperationStatus      : Succeeded
```

Anyone can help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I used :

```
Get-AzureRole -ServiceName "serviceNameHere" -Slot "Production" -InstanceDetails | Format-Table -Auto "InstanceName", "InstanceSize", "InstanceStatus"
```

If anyone runs into this anytime soon.